# Sprite Kit iOS7 - SKNode UserData property not storing values

Tags: nsmutablearray, sprite, user-data, sprite-kit

I would think this work work easily, however I cannot understand why my NSMutableDictionary property is not working as I would have expected.

```
[self.testSprite.userData setValue:@"CAT" forKey:@"key"];
NSLog(@"%@", [self.testSprite.userData objectForKey:@"key"]);
NSLog(@"%lu", [self.testSprite.userData count]);
```

I am retuning (null) and 0.

Is there a special trick for using the spriteNode userdata ?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The userData property is initially nil. You have to create a dictionary and assign it first:

```
self.testSprite.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[self.testSprite.userData setValue:@"CAT" forKey:@"key"];
NSLog(@"%@", [self.testSprite.userData objectForKey:@"key"]);
NSLog(@"%lu", [self.testSprite.userData count]);
```

Comment: This almost killed me...thanks!  Why trying to setValue on a nil doesn't throw a warning/error is beyond me.

Comment: Lol this is crazy! Thank you