# Is there a way to setTag/ use tagging in spriteKit on SKNode objects? (like in cocos2d)

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have previously spent a lot of time using cocos2d, and got used to the convenience of tags, which are also available on UIView objects, but currently I started a project using spritekit and cannot find an equivalent.  Thus my question, does anyone know if there is any kind of equivalent to it for SKSpriteNode/SKNode objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `name` property of `SKNode`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/name):

> Used to assign a name to a node for later reference. When choosing a name for a node, you should decide whether each node gets a unique name or whether some nodes will share a common name. If you give the node a unique name, you can find the node later by calling the `childNodeWithName:` method. If a name is shared by multiple nodes, the name usually means that these are all a similar object type in your game. In this case, you can iterate over those objects by calling the `enumerateChildNodesWithName:usingBlock:` method.

Answer (score 6):

Sprite got something way better. Instead of just a tag, within a SKNode you can set a whole dictionary. Say hello to your new friend `.userData?`

Example:

```
   let myNode : SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "make-america-great-again")
   myNode.userData = [
            "keyA" : "blahblah",
            "keyB" : 17.0
        ];

   NSLog("OMFG is this \(myNode.userData?["keyA"]) and \(myNode.userData?["keyB"]) for real!??")
```

Comment: Im using ObjC still. But thanks for this info. Pretty useful property!

Comment: @Rocotilos  You can do this in objective C also. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073199/sprite-kit-ios7-sknode-userdata-property-not-storing-values