# Passing a float between scenes

Tags: objective-c

I pretty much have the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885490/spritekit-passing-data-between-scenes). But it doesn't explain how to retrieve the score from the dictionary. I want to pass a float called score to another scene.

I have the following code in my update method:

```
if (lives == 0) {
    SKScene * nextScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];

    nextScene.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSNumber * scoreForDictionary = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:score];
    [nextScene.userData setObject:scoreForDictionary forKey:@"score"];

    [self.view presentScene:nextScene];
}
```

I have this code in the other scene:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        NSNumber * scoreNumber = [self.view.scene.userData objectForKey:@"score"];
        score = [scoreNumber floatValue];

        [self showScore];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I think this is the way to do it, but it doesn't work. Can you please explain how to pass a float to another scene?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean specifically?

Comment: The score float in the second scene is not set to the value that it had in the previous scene.

Comment: Try ``NSNumber * scoreNumber = [self.userData objectForKey:@"score"];``

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's set to 0

Comment: @Danilo That doesn't work either.

Comment: Whats the output when you ``NSLog(@"%@", self.userData);`` in your second scene?

Comment: And in what method is the code for the second scene?

Comment: @Danilo Ah, the output is: (null). I will edit my post to show the code for the second scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accessing `userData` before its set. In your first scene you are calling:

`SKScene * nextScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];`

Now your

`-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size`

will be called trying to access `userData` which has not been set yet. Move your code in your second scene to a later point like `- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view`