# pass score between scene sprite kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sprite

Im trying to pass my Score from GameScene to `GameOverScene`. 
I just want to set the text of the label in the `GameOverScene` with my variable Score that I passed to it.
I am using this:

```
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
    SKScene *currentScene = [spriteView scene];
    GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.frame.size];
    [gameOverScene.userData setObject:[currentScene.userData objectForKey:@"score"] forKey:@"score"];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:[SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:1]]; // animation
```

How do I access the score variable now in my GameOverScene?

Thanks for any answers.

EDIT:

Okay I have a variable int Score; . How do I connect the `objectForKey@"score"` to this variable?

EDIT2:

```
[score setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %@", [self.userData valueForKey:@"score"]]];
```

With that I get Score: `(null)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885490/spritekit-passing-data-between-scenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize `userData` for **GameScene** in `didMoveToView`:

```
self.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

After that, if you want to save your integer `score`, add:

```
score = 100;    // assume your score is 100 now
[self.userData setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score] forKey:@"score"];
```

Right before presenting the next scene, edit the code you posted in the question like this:

```
SKView *spriteView = (SKView *)self.view;
SKScene *currentScene = [spriteView scene];
GameOverScene *gameOverScene = [GameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.frame.size];

// Initialize userData for the next scene
gameOverScene.userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[gameOverScene.userData setObject:[currentScene.userData objectForKey:@"score"] forKey:@"score"];
NSLog(@"GameScene score: %lu", [[currentScene.userData objectForKey:@"score"] integerValue]);

[self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition:[SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:1]];
```

Now you should see your new scene and check the score wherever needed:

```
int score = [[self.userData objectForKey:@"score"] intValue];
NSLog(@"GameOverScene score: %d", score);
```

Comment: But how do I give my variable Score to my key score? Its not working the way I have it

Comment: @Robin Have you set integer `score` to your `userData` in **GameScene** already?

Comment: No, how can I do that ?