# How to go to a different scene when paused and back when unpaused

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have 3 scenes - a start game scene,a game scene, and a pause game scene.

I have the pause game scene with a home button that goes back to the start game scene and a play button I want to be able to un-pause the game.

I also have a pause button on my game scene that brings me to the pause game scene.

**Requirement** -
How do I go save the current game board, score, and all so it can be playable after the play button is clicked?

**NOTE** - I don't feel this question needs code to help with answering the question, but if it does I will gladly add it.

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I go save the current game board, score and all"? Do you want to save values? Or do you want the gameScene to resume from where it was before clicking pause; i.e. run both the scenes at once?

Comment: @user5713130 Do you really need to make a transition to the new scene (PauseScene) when game is paused ? You can just tap on pause button and pop up a pause menu (eg. SKSpriteNode or whatever you use to present a pause menu). That way, you don't need to think how to preserve current game state between transitions.

Comment: If you are still into preserving data between transitions, you can check out userData property which every node has (SKScene is a node as well). Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18924419/3402095) Or you can go with a global struct which defines current game state. Still, I would go without transition to the PauseScene if it isn't really required.

Comment: The idea of the pause menu is good, I think I will take that route as a pause scene isn't really necessary as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding subview(Pause Scene) containing Home Button and Play Button on Game Scene. Once Play Button is clicked remove subview(Pause Scene) from Game Scene.

Comment: [self.view addSubview:pauseSceneView];