# Swift, SpriteKit, pass variable to other scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I created a score variable in my GameScene. Now I want to see the result in another scene, for example GameOverScene.
How I can do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SpriteKit: Passing data between scenes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18885490/spritekit-passing-data-between-scenes)

Comment: Please stop marking and saying that question is dublicate if all answers are in Objective-C.

Answer (score 7):

You need always try to post some code on stack overflow.

There is loads of way to do what you want.

1) You could use NSUserDefaults, to save the score and access the saved property in another scene and than assigns it to a new score variable.

2) You could make the score property static, so in gameScene you would say

```
 static var score = 0
```

and than anywhere in your project you can say

```
GameScene.score = 5
```

Remember to reset your score to 0 after every game because static properties are having 1 instance only, i.e. they exist for the lifetime of the app.

3) Yet another way is to do a singleton class

```
class GameData {
    static let shared = GameData()
    var score = 0

    private init() { }
}
```

Than in your SKscenes you either say

```
 let gameData = GameData.shared
 gameData.score = 5
```

or

```
 GameData.shared.score = 5
```